# Numba - memory address of argument (numpy array) from inside jitted function

Tags: python, numba

I was trying to check whether `numba` passes arguments by value or by reference, So I wrote this:

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def f(x):
    return id(x)
```

Which, when run, resulted in this:

```
TypingError: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

This totally makes sense (I know `id` is not necessarily the memory address, but that's what I had in mind). However:

1. How can I get the memory address of an argument within a jitted function?
2. Does numba pass arguments by value or by reference (and how can I verify this)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of the call to `id`, you can only use python features that are listed in:

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html

My understanding is that numba follows python's convention of pass-by-reference vs pass-by-value (although it's really neither exactly). It's more like call-by-object. Immutable objects like scalars act like they are passed by value. Mutable objects like lists and arrays behave like a reference.

The easiest way to confirm this is just try passing in variables of different argument types, modify them within the function and see if they change after the function is called.